# What does this char string related piece of C++ code do?

Tags: c++, string, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
bool check(const char *text) {
    char c;
    while (c = *text++) {
        if ((c & 0x80) && ((*text) & 0x80)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What's `0x80` and the what does the whole mysterious function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting to be less compact:

```
while (true)
{
    char c = *text;
    text += 1;
    if (c == '\0') // at the end of string?
        return false;
    
    int temp1 = c & 0x80;          // test MSB of c
    int temp2 = (*text) & 0x80;    // test MSB of next character
    if (temp1 != 0 && temp2 != 0)  // if both set the return true
        return true;
}
```

MSB means Most Significant Bit. Bit7. Zero for plain ascii characters

Comment: @AdrianMole good point, hows pandora

Answer (score 12):

Testing the result of an `x & 0x80` expression for non-zero (as is done twice in the code you show) checks if the most significant bit (bit 7) of the `char` operand (`x`) is set<sup>1</sup>. In your case, the code loops through the given string looking for two *consecutive* characters (`c`, which is a copy of the 'current' character, and `*test`, the next one) with that bit set.

If such a combination is found, the function returns `true`; if it is not found and the loop reaches the `nul` terminator (so that the `c = *text++` expression becomes zero), it returns `false`.

As to *why* it does such a check – I can only guess but, if that upper bit *is* set, then the character will not be a standard ASCII value (and *may* be the first of a Unicode pair, or some other multi-byte character representation).

---

Possibly helpful references:

- [Bitwise operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators)
- [Hexadecimal constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this bitwise AND test is really the only *safe* way to check that bit, because the C++ Standard allows the `char` type to be either `signed` (where testing for a negative value would be an alternative) or `unsigned` (where testing for >= 128 would be required); either of those tests would fail if the implementation's `char` had the 'wrong' type of signedness.

Answer (score 3):

I can't be totally sure without more context, but it looks to me like this function checks to see if a string contains any UTF-8 characters outside the classic 7-bit US-ASCII range.

`while (c=*text++)` will loop until it finds the nul-terminator in a C-style string; assigning each `char` to `c` as it goes.  `c & 0x80` checks if the most-significant-bit of `c` is set.  `*text & 0x80` does the same for the `char` pointed to by `text` (which will be the one after `c`, since it was incremented as part of the `while` condition).

Thus this function will return `true` if any two adjacent `char`s in the string pointed to by `text` have their most-significant-bit set.  That's the case for any code points U+0080 and above in UTF-8; hence my guess that this function is for detecting UTF-8 text.

Comment: For reference: https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html#is-utf-8

Comment: The code is merely checking whether there are 2 consecutive chars with their high-most bits set to 1.  That is nothing to do with UTF-8 itself.  In fact, anywhere from 2-4 chars are required to detect a proper Unicode character sequence in UTF-8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure.  Detecting UTF-8 is just my guess as to _why_ someone would want to detect consecutive chars with the msb set to 1.  It's not necessarily the _correct_ way to detect UTF-8, but it's the sort of thing someone could write as a quick-and-dirty guess.